# Как циклически отправлять скрытую форму yii2

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, yii2

Добрый день, имею форму

```
    <form method="POST" id="formx">
    <input type="hidden" id="qiwi" name="name" value="<?= $amount ?>" type="text">
    <input type="hidden" id="currency" name="currency" value="<?= $currency ?>" type="text">
    <input type="hidden" id="wallet" name="wallet" value="<?= $wallet ?>" type="text">
</form>
```

JS код, отправляющий ее с интервалом

```
function poll() {
 var msg = $(\'#formx\').serialize();
            $.ajax({
                url: "/checkqiwipayment",
                type: "POST",
                data: msg,
                success: function(data) {
                    console.log("polling");
                },
                dataType: "json"
        });
    }

setInterval(poll, 3500);
')
```

Как принять ее данные в контроллере? Такой способ ничего не выдает

```
if(\Yii::$app->request->isAjax){
$data = Yii::$app->request->post();
var_dump($data);
```

Comment: `var msg = $(\'#formx\').serialize();` - к чему тут экрнирование?

Comment: IDE сама проставила т.к. этот код внутри $this->registerJs(' ');

Comment: Что выводит `$name = Yii::$app->request->post('name');`

Comment: И посмотрите в консоли браузера, отправляются ли данные. И проверьте `var_dump($_POST);`

Comment: Ничего не выводит и данные, как я понял тоже не идут

Comment: Проблема не в этом коде, с ним всё в порядке

Comment: А в чём она может быть?  Сам по себе роут отрабатывает, просто данные, видимо, не получает

Comment: Страница их отправляет? в браузете нажмите F12 и зайдите во вкладку "Сеть"

Comment: Сами запросы идут. Форма по-моему в них не передаётся. Когда делаю простым сабмитом без AJAX - всё окей передаётся и ответ какой надо

Comment: Мб форму как-то по другому отправлять?

Comment: Уберите `dataType: "json"`

Comment: Убрал, ответ не изменился

Comment: Замените `console.log("polling");` на `console.log(data);`. Что выводит в консоль?

Comment: Ну я на вывод в контроллере поставил var_dump, он возвращает пустой массив <pre class='xdebug-var-dump' dir='ltr'>
<small>C:\OSPanel\domains\exchanger.local\app\controllers\OrderController.php:132:</small>
<b>array</b> <i>(size=0)</i>
  <i><font color='#888a85'>empty</font></i>
</pre>

Comment: В скрипте случаной не проверяете `if ($_POST['submit'])` ?

Comment: Добавьте код PHP в вопрос

Comment: У вас CSRF защита включена. Добавьте csrf ключ в запрос или выключите csrf проверку в контроллере

Comment: Всё что у меня на данный момент в контроллере - добавил. Сейчас попробую csrf

Comment: и с csrf и без него - данные не выводятся

Answer (score 0):

В общем решил вот так :

```
function poll() {

        $.ajax({
            url: "/checkqiwipayment",
            type: "POST",
           data: {
             qiwi: $("#qiwi").val() , 
             currency:$("#currency").val() , 
             wallet:$("#wallet").val() ,
             _csrf : '<?=Yii::$app->request->getCsrfToken()?>'
         },
            success: function(data) {
                console.log(data);
            },
    });
}
```

И форму убрал, оставив только поля.

```
<input type="hidden" id="qiwi" name="name" value="<?= $amount ?>" type="text">
<input type="hidden" id="currency" name="currency" value="<?= $currency ?>" type="text">
<input type="hidden" id="wallet" name="wallet" value="<?= $wallet ?>" type="text">
```

Answer (score 0):

Добрый день.
Можно ещё решить проблему следующим методом.
В контроллере, для определённого действия, отключить проверку csrf

```
public function beforeAction($action)
{
    if ($action->id == 'your_name_action') {
        $this->enableCsrfValidation = false;
    }

    return parent::beforeAction($action);
}
```

Или, что будет правильней, не городить огород с отключением проверки csrf, а использовать yii\widgets\ActiveForm или yii\helpers\Html::biginForm().
И можно будет смело использовать `$('form').serialize()`